# Почему с++ компилируемый?

Tags: c++, дизайн-языка

Я изучаю базу программирования, нужен развернутый четкий и понятный ответ на вопрос:
почему с++ проектировался как компилируемый язык?
Никакой информации в гугле не нашел на эту тему, да и дело в том, что не знаю как правильно составить поисковой запрос. Поэтому прошу объяснить, как начинающему.

Comment: Язык C проектировался как компилируемый язык для максимальной производительности. Язык C++ унаследовал эту черту от C для совместимости.

Comment: как говориться : "by design" :)

Comment: У Вас другие предложения? Любой интерпретируемый язык должен чем-то интерпретироваться А на чем писать интерпретатор? И чем интерпретировать его? Как ни раскручивай, всё равно придётся дойти до компилируемого языка. Да, компилятор тоже на чём-то должен быть написан. Но и в этой цепочке тоже дойдём до компилируемого языка. Так какой смысл интерпретируемых языков кроме учебных, малышей и изначально предназначенных именно для разработки программ, управляющих другими программами? На VBA не кивать, у него именно такое назначение – программы. управляющие другими программами.

Comment: Ну ещё софтпроцессоры и прочие аппаратные интерпретаторы хоть как-то могут оправдать сугубо нишевые интерпретируемые языки, не относящиеся к указанным категориям. Например, интерпретирумый язык разметки страниц для постскрипт принтера оправдан: если принтер не умеет такое интерпретировать, то он не постскрипт принтер, а если умеет, то интерпретатор уже зашит в саму машину, целиком принтер – аппаратный интерпретатор. А программы на javasript управляют браузером, а не самим компьютером.

Comment: Так что предложите? Софтпроцессор для плюсов? Это сугубо нишевое решение, не переносимое на компы на других процессорах. Интерпретатор в ПЗУ? Даже на спектруме есть компилятор языка бейсик по имени бласт, после компиляции которым программы на бейсике на том же спектруме работают в 50 раз быстрей.

Comment: Проголосовал за, так как вопрос-то хорош. А вот ответ на него должен наводить на мысли.

Answer (score 7):

Язык Си проектировался как системный язык. Его создатель Деннис Ритчи,в те года занимался разработкой ОС Unix, последующие версии которого по большей части и были переписаны на язык Си. Интерпретируемые языки были в данной ситуации неуместы. Язык C++, автором которого стал Бьёрне Страуструп, был улучшением языка Си, главным отличием стала ООП парадигма. Разумеется, в следствие наследственности, язык С++ остался компилируемым и даже обладает полной обратной совместимостью с языком Си.

UPD (спасибо Станиславу за комментарий):
В момент разработки C++ обладал полной обратной совместимостью. Первоначально он был реализован как препроцессор, порождающий код на C: "Разрабатывая C с классами, Страуструп написал программу cfront — транслятор, перерабатывающий исходный код C с классами в исходный код простого C.". Потом стандарты расходились всё дальше и дальше

Comment: Ну не полной совместимостью всё же.

Comment: @tocic, в  момент разработки C++ обладал полной обратной совместимостью. Первоначально он был реализован как препроцессор, порождающий код на C: "Разрабатывая C с классами, Страуструп написал программу cfront — транслятор, перерабатывающий исходный код C с классами в исходный код простого C.". Потом стандарты расходились всё дальше и дальше.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy стоит добавить это в ответ. В текущем виде кажется, что "обладает" значит "в данный момент".

Comment: @tocic, благодарю за замечания, не обладал в полной мере знанием, что действительно уже стандарты сильно расходятся

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, благодарю за уточнение, дополню ответ

Comment: Когда-то читал эту историю. Похоже, что C++ (C с классами) появился потому, что в Bell Labs в тот момент не нашлось достаточно мощного компьютера с языком Симула, на котором Страуструп собирался моделировать (в продолжении своей диссертации) телекоммуникационную сеть для работ, выполняемых Bell Labs. К тому же, в соседних с Страуструпом комнатах  работали Керниган и Ритчи